# Pieradmin install error: Missing class ImageSegment

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I'm attempting to install [Pieradmin](http://pieradmin.seasidehosting.st) on a clean image of [Pharo 1.4 (Summer)](http://www.pharo-project.org/pharo-download), using the commands:

```
Gofer it
    renggli: 'pier2addons';
    package: 'ConfigurationOfPierAdmin';
    load.

ConfigurationOfPierAdmin loadBleedingEdge.
```

It progresses for a while and comes up with the error:

```
This package depends on the following classes:
    ImageSegment
You must resolve these dependencies before you will be able to load these definitions: 
    writeKernel:on:
```

You can proceed and it will finish installing all its dependencies.

I have two questions:

- Where can I get the class ImageSegment?
- Or, if I can't, does it matter that writeKernel:on: isn't there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nathan,

The dependency on ImageSegment is almost certainly coming from the package `Pier-Pharo-Persistency` defined in `ConfigurationOfPier2>>baseline2060:` where it is included as part of `Core` group for Pier ... which at first glance makes it appear that the `Pier-Pharo-Persistency` is pretty much required for Pier.

You could fiddle with the `ConfigurationOfPier2>>baseline2060:` and remove `Pier-Pharo-Persistency` from the `Core` group, then try the load again, but you may just be creating another more subtle problem for yourself. It's probably a good idea to ask this question on the [Pier mailing list](https://www.iam.unibe.ch/mailman/listinfo/smallwiki)

OTOH, I'm pretty sure that `Pier-Admin` works in Pharo-1.3 so that would be your best option.

Dale

Answer (score 3):

Yes, ImageSegment was removed from Pharo 1.4. And ReferenceStream was also removed from Pharo 2.0. The idea was to rely on new and better tools like Fuel serializer (see http://rmod.lille.inria.fr/web/pier/software/Fuel).

Yanni and me have done 2 things: Pier persistence and kernel export/import based on Fuel. You can find the code in:

```
Gofer it
    squeaksource3: 'pierfuel';
    package: 'Pier-FuelPersistence-Core';
    package: 'Pier-FuelPersistence-Test';
    load.
```

Then you can do, for example:

```
 PRFuelExporterImporter new exportKernelNamed: 'pierDBX' toFilename: 'pierDBX.fuel'
```

And:

```
 PRFuelExporterImporter new importNewKernelNamed: 'pierDBX' fromFilename: 'pierDBX.fuel'
```